# Delete element from multiple array cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

Is there an easy way to delete a Subelement from a CakePHP array, such that `foreach ($junta)`?
I have this array `$junta` with diverses elements and i want remove `[password] => 3d0f93c607cfe638f9421d4af49a3455`

Use this code :

```
$index = array_search('password',$junta);
if($index !== FALSE){
    unset($junta[$index]); }
```

And don't work.

Value of `$junta`:

```
Array
(
    [junta] => Array
        (
            [Council] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 21
                    [descripcion] => esta es una prueba 7
                    [version] => 
                    [imagen] => Cuadernillo de higiene y seguridad Industrial.pdf
                    [archivo] => 21
                    [director] => 
                    [fecha] => 2016-04-07
                    [user_id] => 1
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [username] => jflores
                    [password] => 3d0f93c607cfe638f9421d4af49a
                    [nombres] => Antonio
                    [Apellido_P] => flores lara
                    [Apellido_M] => 
                    [created] => 2016-03-13 01:57:37
                    [email] => antonioflores30@gmail.com
                    [role] => king
                    [modified] => 2016-03-13 02:21:39
                    [status] => 1
                )

        )

    [consejeros] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [CouncilorsCouncil] => Array
                        (
                            [councilor_id] => 2
                            [council_id] => 21
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select the fields that you need.

**CakePHP 2**

```
$this->MyModel->find('All',array(
    'fields' => array('User.username','User.email',....),
    'conditions' => ...
));
```

CakePHP 3

```
$this->MyModel->find()
    ->select(['User.username','User.email',....])
    ->where(...)
    -> ....
));
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete only `password` field try this

```
$result = Hash::remove($arr2, 'junta.User.password');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example it looked like you were trying to unset the value instead of unsetting the key of the value. For the exact example you have shown this should work:

`if(isset($junta['junata']['User']['password'])){
 unset($junta[junata]['User']['password']);
}`